# Keycloak version upgrade from 10 to 16

Tags: kubernetes, migration, keycloak

I am currently moving from keycloak 10 to keycloak 16. I deployed new version with helm chart and connected to my postgres db. But in admin console only groups are showing up and nothing else (realms, etc...). I searched the docs and it said that no migrations scripts for version 16 are available. What steps should I take in order to get it working with my postgres db. I think they changed schemas.

**SOLVED**

The problem occurred due to dump was loaded with errors.
I just deleted all schemas in keycloak db and re-uploaded dump, so it is working now.

Comment: Did you try the export and import functionality ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.